# How to reorder a vector to matrix without loop?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Here is my task

I have a vector like this

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11];
```

I want to have a matrix like this:

```
b = [1 2 3;
     3 4 5;
     5 6 7;
     7 8 9;
     9 10 11];
```

That is in every two elements I pick three elements.
In general, I want pick `m` elements in every `k` elements.

I know how to do it with a loop, but I want to ask if there is a way that can do it without a loop in MATLAB.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the example, what should be the result when `m = k = 2`?

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro I imagine it would be undefined for this `a`. Good question!

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro good question, this will not happen, thank you @@"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That pattern appears in the hankel matrix.

```
ha = hankel(a');
b = ha(1:k:end-m+1, 1:m);
```

Comment: It's a good solution, but look out for memory usage in practice, as `ha` is square.

Answer (score 4):

To pick `m` elements every `k` elements:

```
inds = bsxfun(@plus,(1:m),(0:k:(numel(a)-m)).')
a(inds)
```

Comment: I think your ending index is wrong, since you can reach `numel(a)-k+m`

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you, that should have been a `-m` instead. It didn't manifest an error in this example because `colon` couldn't get there with a step of `k`.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something like this, but I'm not sure it works for all cases:

```
a(cumsum([1:m; ones(floor((numel(a) - m) / k), m) * k]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
m = 3;
k = 2;
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11]; %// length should be {a multiple of k} plus m

result = reshape(a(1:floor(numel(a)/k)*k), k, []);
result = [result; result(1:m-k,2:end) a(end-m+k+1:end).'].';
```